# What VSCODE Extension that turns short tags and classes sentence into expanded code (example inside)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

What extension does this in visual studio code

`ul.menu > li.item*3 > a.link#www.code.com > Click Me`

it will exchange it with

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li class="item"><a class="link" a="www.code.com">Click Me</a></li>
   <li class="item"><a class="link" a="www.code.com">Click Me</a></li>
   <li class="item"><a class="link" a="www.code.com">Click Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `emmet` - it is built-in.

Comment: It doesn't work on VSCODE!
Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues.

1. Remove the spaces, emmet won't work "across" spaces.
2. You have `a="www.code.com"` I assume you mean `id="www.code.com"`, but that is problematic because of the `.`'s which emmet will interpret as more classes in this: `a.link#www.code.com`.  That can be fixed with the custom attribute syntax `[attributeName="attributeValue"]`.  See https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#custom-attributes
3. Your final text has a space too so wrap it in `{}`

So you will have to do:

`ul.menu>li.item*3>a.link[id="www.code.com"]{Click Me}`

which expands to:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item"><a href="" class="link" id="www.code.com">Click Me</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="" class="link" id="www.code.com">Click Me</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="" class="link" id="www.code.com">Click Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you really mean `a="www.code.com"` as an attribute then make that a custom attribute as in `ul.menu>li.item*3>a.link[a="www.code.com"]{Click Me}`

Finally, emmet is expecting a `href` attribute and value since it is an `a` tag.  If you don't want one, let us know - you might be able to eliminate that with a custom emmet snippet.